# XmlNode keeps saying there is no nodes but there is

Tags: c#, xml, get

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FValue = id.Text;
            string SValue = id2.Text;
            string ending;
            string url = "http://localhost:56254/api/add?id=" + FValue + "&id2=" + SValue;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1";
            client.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            string data = client.DownloadString(url);
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

            xdoc.LoadXml(data);
   -->      XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("End");
            ending = xnode.InnerText;
            Answer.Text = ending;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code that keeps giving me a null at ending and if I put a breaker at arrow it tells me count = 0. Here is my xml:

```
- <Calcs xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Calculator.Models">
              <End>10</End> 
              <FValue>5</FValue> 
              <SValue>5</SValue> 
  </Calcs>
```

And when I call End it keeps telling me no node is called End.... and keeps giving me null am I doing something wrong?
http://i45.tinypic.com/24cgkld.png

Comment: make sure your xdoc has xml data

Comment: It does have all the data and the first child id "Calcs" then First Child is End after that so the xdoc has everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectSingleNode` method is expecting an XPath expression, try this:

```
XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//End");
```

EDIT: It's a namespace problem, try the below:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cm", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Calculator.Models");

XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//cm:End", nsmgr);
```

Comment: That worked for me, your xdoc must be empty or you are not giving us the full XML.

Comment: nope it still doesn't work I can post my exact values from screenshot I will post pics one sec

Comment: Thank you so much just finished my application thanks a lot :D

Comment: Hey can you explain what cm is ?

Comment: It's just an alias for the namespace, you could put anything there instead of "cm".

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode xnode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Calcs/End");
```